# junit event driven testing

Tags: java, junit

It's my first time on testing (yes, i've never run a test before, but it's never to late to get started, isn't it?)

I'd a parser that parses a buffer, and dispatch an event).

Calling the parser:

```
parser.parse((ByteBuffer) readBuffer.duplicate().flip(), key);
```

parse method:

```
@Override
public void parse(final ByteBuffer buffer, final SelectionKey key) {
    //Parse some stuff here and then dispatch a new event

    eventDispatcher.dispatch(new ConnectionDataReadyArgs(key, host.toString(), port));
}
```

event handler:

```
@Override
public void handle(final ConnectionDataReadyArgs args) {
    //Do stuff here with the recieved args
}
```

How do I create a junit test that checks if the arguments received on the event handler are right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with writing tests after writing the code, is that you may not have designed the code for testability.

*Dependency injection* makes code easier to test. If you're lucky, you're already injecting the `eventDispatcher`. If not, it would help to make it so, by making the `eventDispatcher` a constructor parameter:

```
  public MyClass(EventDispatcher eventDispatcher) {
       this.eventDispatcher = eventDispatcher;
  }
```

(You could also use a setter -- but I prefer to make my objects immutable)

Once you've done that, you can inject a test `EventDispatcher`:

```
  class TestEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {
       public Event event;
       public EventDispatchChain tail;

       public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
            this.event = event;
            this.tail = tail;
            return null;
       }
  }

  TestEventDispatcher testDispatcher = new TestEventDispatcher();
  MyClass testObject = new MyClass(testDispatcher);
  testObject.dosomething();
  assertThat(testDispatcher.event, someMatcher(...));
```

A *mocking framework* such as Mockito or JMock provides a dynamic and fluent way of creating mock objects for this purpose. It's better in many ways than creating ad-hoc static test implementations as I've done here. Read the introductory documentation for either of these.

This is for *unit testing*. You probably also want some integration tests that use a real `EventDispatcher` along with several of your own objects, checking that when something happens in object A, the `eventDispatcher` triggers and something happens in object B.

Comment: that's an example of a perfect answer. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I'm already using guice for DP. Thank you very much for your answer, I'd go with this aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Check for side effects. Add accessor methods in the event handler so that you can check if the values being passed are correct. You can also make it write to a file and assert it if the file contents are correct.

Comment: jpllosa, could you explain with more datails what you are suggesting please? Maybe I did not understand, I cant follow you, sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to test it, you have to understan that you have to decide if your method will have a Precondition or not, it means, you can assume that the parameter received are always correct, so, in your code, you will ensure that.
 If you decide the opposite, you can throw an exception if the arguments ar not what you expected, and then test if the method throws that exception or not:

So, if you go for the second way, you can create a exeption class like:

```
public class IlegalArgumentForXFunction extends Exeption {} //just an example
```

And then you add it to your function:

```
@Override
public void handle(final ConnectionDataReadyArgs args) throws IlegalArgumentForXFunction{
    if(args.checkIfAreIllegals == true){
        throw new IlegalArgumentForXFunction();
    }
    //Do stuff here with the recieved args
}
```

Then you create your unit test, something like:

```
@Test(expected = IlegalArgumentForXFunction.class) 
public void testIfArgumentsAreIllegal() { 
     Myclass mc = new MyClass;
     ConnectionDataReadyArgs arg = new ConnectionDataReadyArgs(); //invalid args
     mc.handle(arg);
}
```

You can check sources [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing)